# How to use parameter referenced_sticker_id in Facebook graph api me/videos..?

Tags: android

```
   Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.put("file_url","video_url")
params.put("title","post video")
new GraphRequest(
AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
"/{page-id}/videos",
params,
HttpMethod.POST,
new GraphRequest.Callback() {
    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
        /* handle the result */
    }
}
).executeAsync();
```

In that particular video posting graph api there is one parameter as per documentation [please have a look](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/).
There is one param referenced_sticker_id which means "Sticker id of the sticker in the post"
but how can i use this parm by which i can share my sticker with video i try it by using image url but it doesn't work.It needs Numeric string or integer value foe sticker.